# How different is type.__setattr__ from object.__setattr__?

Tags: python, metaclass

`type.__setattr__` is used for classes, basically instances of metaclasses.  `object.__setattr__` on the other hand, is used for instances of classes. This is totally understood.

I don't see a significant difference between the two method, at least at Python level, I notice the two use the same procedures for attribute assignment, correct me if I'm wrong:

Suppose `a` is an instance of a user-defined class, just a normal class:

```
class A:
    pass

a = A()
a.x = ...
```

then `a.x = ..` invokes `type(a).__setattr__(...)` which performs the following steps:

*Note: `type(a).__setattr__` will find `__setattr__` in `object` builtin class*

1) Look for a data descriptor in `type(a).__mro__`.

2) If a data descriptor was found, call its `__set__` method and exit.

3) If no data descriptor was found in `type(a).__mro__`, then add attribute to `a.__dict__`, `a.__dict__['x'] = ...`

---

With classes--instances of metaclasses, the process is similar:

```
class A(metaclass=type):
    pass
```

then: `A.x = ...` is translated to `type(A).__setattr__(...)` which performs the following steps:

*Note: `type(A).__setattr__` will find `__setattr__` in `type` builtin class*

1) Look for a data descriptor in `type(A).__mro__`

2) If a data descriptor was found, call its `__set__` method and exit.

3) If no data descriptor was found in `type(A).__mro__`, then add attribute to `A.__dict__`, `a.__dict__['x'] = ...`

But `object.__setattr__` doesn't work for classes:

```
>>> object.__setattr__(A, 'x', ...)
TypeError: can't apply this __setattr__ to type object
```

and vice versa, `type.__setattr__` doesn't work for instances of `A`:

```
>>> type.__setattr__(A(), 'x', ...)
TypeError: descriptor '__setattr__' requires a 'type' object but received a 'A'
```

Hmmm! There must be something different between the two methods. This is subtle, but true nonetheless!

Presumably the two methods perform the same steps inside `__setattr__`, what is the difference between `type.__setattr__` and `object.__setattr__` so that `type.__setattr__` is limited to classes and `object.__setattr__` is limited to instances of classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`type.__setattr__` has a check to prevent setting attributes on types like `int`, and it does a bunch of invisible cleanup that isn't needed for normal objects.

---

Let's take a look under the hood! Here's [`type.__setattr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/typeobject.c#L3075):

```
static int
type_setattro(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *name, PyObject *value)
{
    if (!(type->tp_flags & Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE)) {
        PyErr_Format(
            PyExc_TypeError,
            "can't set attributes of built-in/extension type '%s'",
            type->tp_name);
        return -1;
    }
    if (PyObject_GenericSetAttr((PyObject *)type, name, value) < 0)
        return -1;
    return update_slot(type, name);
}
```

and if we examine [`PyBaseObject_Type`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/typeobject.c#L4508), we see it uses `PyObject_GenericSetAttr` for its `__setattr__`, the same call that appears halfway through `type_setattro`.

Thus, `type.__setattr__` is like `object.__setattr__`, but with some additional handling wrapped around it.

First, the `if (!(type->tp_flags & Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE))` check prohibits attribute assignment on types written in C, like `int` or `numpy.array`, because assigning attributes on those can seriously screw up the Python internals in ways someone unfamiliar with the C API might not expect.

Second, after the `PyObject_GenericSetAttr` call updates the type's dict or calls an appropriate descriptor from the metaclass, `update_slot` fixes up any *slots* affected by the attribute assignment. These slots are C-level function pointers that implement functionality like instance allocation, `in` checks, `+`, deallocation, etc. Most of them have corresponding Python-level methods, like `__contains__` or `__add__`, and if one of those Python-level methods is reassigned, the corresponding slot (or slots) have to be updated, too. `update_slot` also updates slots on all descendants of the class, and it invalidates entries in an internal attribute cache used for type object attributes.

Comment: One question about the second step you mentioned. Let's say `Klass` started out initially without the `__contains__`. and `__contains__` was assigned after the class was created.if I assign to a class like: `Klass.__contains__ = ...`,  `PyObject_GenericSetAttr` will update `Klass.__dict__` and `update_slot` will update the slot of `__contain__`? This also means `__contains__` slot for `Klass` was initially `Null` before assignment?

Comment: @direprobs: `update_slot` will set the slot corresponding to `__contains__`. That slot is `->tp_as_sequence->sq_contains`, and more than just `sq_contains` being null, it might not have even existed yet, since `tp_as_sequence` itself could have been null. (None of this should ever be important to you unless you need to work with the C API.)