# In python, what's the relationship between the built-in function 'setattr()' and 'object.__setattr__()'?

Tags: python

what's the relationship between the built-in function 'setattr()' and 'object.__setattr__()'? Is the built-in function "getattr(obj,attr)" totally equal to obj.attr?

Comment: check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739608/how-different-is-type-setattr-from-object-setattr

Comment: regarding getattr: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#data-model) regarding these methods? If yes, tell us what you didn't understand. Otherwise people will be basically explaining the same here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \_\_getattr\_\_ vs \_\_getattribute\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute)